# rename a database name in db2 server

Tags: db2-luw

I have a db2 server and i need to rename the database in the server. i created the configuration file:

```
DB_NAME=E2P,E2POLD
DB_PATH=/db2/E2P
INSTANCE=db2e2p
NODENUM=0
```

and then started the database instance and executed the relocatedb command:

```
db2relocatedb -f relocate.cfg
```

but this is giving me the following error:

```
DBT1006N  The file/device "/db2/E2P/db2e2p/NODE0000/SQL00001/" could not be opened.
```

I have checked and there are no blank spaces in the configuration file. Please suggest what is going wrong here?

Also i chekced the diaglog and saw the follwoing error over ther:

```
2015-04-11-04.22.18.593830-240 I481891E628         LEVEL: Error
PID     : 26289                TID  : 46931183135040PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2e2p               NODE : 000          DB   : E2P
APPHDL  : 0-36                 APPID: *LOCAL.DB2.150411082246
AUTHID  : DB2Q01
EDUID   : 88                   EDUNAME: db2evmgi (DB2DETAILDEADLOCK) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database monitor, sqmEvmonWriter::initTarget, probe:40
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x800D002C=-2146631636=SQLM_RC_EVPATH "path in use"
DATA #1 : String, 17 bytes
DB2DETAILDEADLOCK
DATA #2 : String with size, 60 bytes
/db2/E2P/db2e2p/NODE0000/SQL00001/db2event/db2detaildeadlock

2015-04-11-04.22.18.594489-240 I482520E528         LEVEL: Error
PID     : 26289                TID  : 46931183135040PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2e2p               NODE : 000          DB   : E2P
APPHDL  : 0-36                 APPID: *LOCAL.DB2.150411082246
AUTHID  : DB2Q01
EDUID   : 88                   EDUNAME: db2evmgi (DB2DETAILDEADLOCK) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database monitor, sqmEvmonWriter::activate, probe:40
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x800D002C=-2146631636=SQLM_RC_EVPATH "path in use"
DATA #1 : String, 17 bytes
DB2DETAILDEADLOCK
```

would system reboot be helpful here?

Comment: May be you want to drop the event monitor DB2DETAILDEADLOCK -- it's deprecated anyway.

Comment: Ensure that the instance is stopped

Comment: I have same problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to run below similar mv command:
mv /home/db2inst1/db2inst1/NODE0000/E2P /home/db2inst1/db2inst1/NODE0000/E2POLD
before executing db2relocate command.

Here is one of good articles for your situation:

**[Db2] Simple test case shell script for db2relocatedb command**
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/1099185

It tells basic usage of db2relocatedb command.

Hope this helps.